# If a device has UR sign on the label, it called it is UL approved or not?

Tags: ul

In the data sheet for a device there is a code to indicate it is UL approved.
on the label this code not there but there is a sign UR.
IS UR also can called it is UL approved?
or
UL approved not just mean that it is UL listed it also can mean it is UR?

Comment: Google "Recognized UL" mark. In laymans terms "backwards RU = UL approved" but when you look deeper into the question, RU is a different level than just UL.

Answer (score 2):

UL does not use the term "approved." The data sheet is apparently marked to indicate that the device has some kind of UL certification without saying the specific type of certification.

The UL mark is used for certified products. UL listed products could be electrically powered equipment or appliances, and also devices for power distribution wiring.

The UR mark is used for components of products that would need a UL product listing. When a product made with UR recognized components is submitted to UL listing, UL does not need to investigate the components in detail but only review their use in the final product, the manner of final construction etc. UL listed panel shops construct certain types of products that are custom-made or manufactured in low quantities. If the products are made with UR marked components following UL guidelines, the maker can apply the UL label without submitting each different product for UL certification. UL representatives visit the shops for periodic inspections.